# Embedding networkD3 in R Markdown, why this error?

Tags: r, r-markdown, networkd3

I'm trying to add a network graph to an R Markdown file write a paper.  I'm able to make the graph just fine using NetworkD3 to visualise it.  I'd like to create an interactive HTML, but I keep getting errors.  Here is an example:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
```{r}
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target)
simpleNetwork(networkData)
```
````

I then get this error, which is very similar to the errors I get when trying to embed my own graph.

```
processing file: w.Rmd
  |........                                                         |  12%
  ordinary text without R code

  |................                                                 |  25%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |........................                                         |  38%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
Quitting from lines 12-16 (w.Rmd) 
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  could not find function "simpleNetwork"
Calls: <Anonymous> ... handle -> withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval 
-> eval

Execution halted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.  I have to load my data into the Markdown file.  I found the answer here https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200631198-data-set-not-found-when-knitting-HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `networkD3` package in your setup, like this...

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(networkD3)
```
```{r}
src <- c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D")
target <- c("B", "C", "D", "J", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I")
networkData <- data.frame(src, target)
simpleNetwork(networkData)
```
````

Comment: CJ Yetman, thanks, I'm still getting an error when running my data.  I'll work to create a replicable example.

Comment: Getting "an error" is not the same as getting "this error" as described in your question. You should update your question or open a new question for the benefit of other people that end up here.